# DateFormat Not Parsing Date Correctly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse to Java Date Strings of type "Mar 28,2017 13:00".

I wrote following code

```
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,YYYY HH:mm");
        System.out.println(df.parse(dateTime));
```

This code seems to parse hour and minutes correctly, but the date is always Jan 1, 2017. e.g. for String given above, output is "Sun Jan 01 13:00:00 IST 2017"

Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Comment: Well what `dateTime` are you trying to parse?

Comment: dateTime is String of type "Mar 28,2017 13:00". Input is guaranteed to be in this format.

Comment: what is the output format you want?

Comment: Issue here was date not being parsed correctly. Both the answers below worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(df.parse("Mar 28,2017 13:00"));
```

Comment: Wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with how you written Date and Time pattern. It Should be

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm");
```

Please refer 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to correct the pattern:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(df.parse("Mar 28,2017 12:00"));
// Tue Mar 28 12:00:00 CEST 2017
```

**Explanation:** Using the symbol "Y" indicates the year-of-weekdate (or called week-based-year). It is not the calendar year and can only be combined in a sensible way with week-of-year and day-of-week. But your pattern only contains month and day-of-month, so `SimpleDateFormat` just uses default values for week-of-year (=1) and day-of-week (=Sunday) and implicitly the US-standard for week-definition (weeks starting on Sunday). This results in the first calendar week of week-based-year 2017, hence the observed date 2017-01-01.

Use the symbol "y" instead which means the year-of-era (here: the normal calendar year).

**Attention:** Compared with the accepted answer of @Shamil Sungatov, I have chosen the pattern letter "HH" for the hour component, not "hh" (12-hour-clock). This is relevant if your clock hour to be parsed has the value 12 (which would be interpreted in a different way, namely as midnight in case of "hh").